# Regex - detect if word contains lowercase character

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex to determine if a the name of a macro declaration in C is uppercased :

```
#define MY_MACRO
```

In order to detect only the uppercase word (without taking into account special chars like backspaces or hyphens) I am using the following regex:

```
"#define +[^A-Z]+"
```

It works if my macro is full uppercased but fails if it's like :

```
#define Mymacro
```

What is a regex able to determine this case?

Comment: The macro name seems to be delimited by space, so `r"#define\s*\S*[a-z]\S*"` probably will work. The regex will match if there is any lowercase character.

Comment: `[^A-Z]` matches anything that *is not* an uppercase character..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To detect `#define MixedCase` but not match `#define ALLUPPERCASE` you need a negative lookahead assertion:

```
r'#define\s+(?![A-Z_]+\b)[A-Za-z_]+\b'
```

`\b` matches the word boundary; the place where a word ends, perhaps because of whitespace after it, or the end of the line.

The `(?!..)` negative lookahead assertion checks that the next word is *not* all uppercase, before allowing a match on a mixed-case word.

Note that I've included the `_` underscore as well in the matching character class.

You may want to include digits in your macro names, they are legal, after all:

```
r'#define\s+(?![A-Z0-9_]+\b)\w+\b'
```

The second character class can then be simplified to `\w`, which is the same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to match something that _doesn't_ uses uppercase all the way through.

Comment: @Lowip: Right, that's unclear from your message. You want to detect a valid define that isn't using uppercase all the way through? Does it need to use *some* uppercase?

Comment: @msw: I agree, but was echoing the OP.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I need to detect if the define isn't using uppercase all the way through `#define MY_MACRO` should not be detected but `#define My_MACRO` should be detected. Thanks.

Comment: @Lowip: updated my answer. Note that this will also validate an all-lowercase define (`#define lowercase`).

Comment: @nhahtdh: No, a negation also matches non-define lines.

Comment: @nhahtdh @MartijnPieters both `r"#define\s*\S*[a-z]\S*"` and `r'#define\s+(?![A-Z_]+\b)[A-Za-z_]+\b'` work fine for my case. Thanks

Comment: Macro names can also include numeric digits.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: And then we need to define the macro name match more tightly still, as you cannot use a digit to *start* the name.. Still, it'll probably do with what I've entered in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does the regex *have* to do everything? You could just match all the `#define`s with the regex and then test the uppercase-ness of the macro name using some very simple Python code:

```
macro_defn = re.compile(r'#define\s+(\w+)')
for line in code_source:
    macro_match = macro_defn.match(line)
    if macro_match:
        macro_name = macro.group(1)
        if macro_name.upper() != macro_name:
            print line
```